# How to manually set an authResponse from an access token generated during server-side authentication

Tags: oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication, facebook-oauth

I am writing a web application using server-side authentication, and I've been trying to figure out a way to leverage Facebook's Javascript SDK in my application.

The documentation for FB.init defines the optional authResponse parameter as something used to "Manually set the object retrievable from getAuthResponse".  It also states that once obtained, an application may store the entire authResponse object for future access.  This may work if an application uses FB.login, the Javascript SDK's authentication, but what about an app using server-side authentication?

Server-side authentication enables my app to obtain a user's access token, the most crucial piece of information needed for graph API calls.  I would hope that this access_token alone would be enough to construct a valid authResponse object to use to authenticate to use with the Javascript SDK.

Merely calling FB.init (with valid appID, channelUrl, and other parameters) with an authResponse containing a valid "accessToken" field is not sufficient.  Including the userId is also insufficient.  Ideally, these parameters alone would work.  The only others defined for the authResponse are 'expiresIn' and 'signedRequest'.  Which, if either, of these parameters would be sufficient to generate a valid authResponse object?  To what values must they be assigned?

I managed to dig up this description of a 'signedRequest':
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

This document raises a number of questions.  I assume that the signature is produced by a symmetric algorithm.  If not, then generating it would not be possible.  Assuming it is possible, the description of the payload is in no way specific.  There is a list of 9 parameters, none of which are labeled as required.

Comment: You should not need to pass anything manually in this scenario. Have you initialized the JS SDK with `cookie:true`? Try calling FB.getLoginStatus after you did the server-side login – what response does that give you?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for that. I didn't think that it's so easy.

```
FB.api('/me?access_token={{ access_token }}', function (me) {
    console.log(me); //do anything with me
});
```

So you didn't need to set an Objekt Variable in FB before -
simply add the access_token as parameter with your request.

Answer (score 0):

Like CBroe says, you shouldn't be passing anything manually. You start with a call to [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) and pass your javascript handler as an argument to this method. You will have the authResponse returned back from the getLoginStatus call.

You can, of course, in theory pass the access_token param around to any FB.api call e.g. /me?access_token=blah_blah, where blah_blah is the string you have but again, this is not required and you are better off delegating this to the response handlers.

Be very careful when using the javascript sdk and server side authentication for access token generation/extension/verification. You end up maintaining two separate code paths and end up making the same call to Facebook over and over again. Even if you are storing the access token on your side, would be always better to pick one approach that works best for you, rather than having a server side call to get access token and a client side call to FB.api to use the access token.

Comment: In case you're curious, I had already tried what you are suggesting but I was getting an error indicating I was using an invalid access_token.  It turns out that I wasn't waiting for getLoginStatus to complete prior to making an API call.

Comment: Finally, I do believe there is value in being able to manually set an access token when using the javascript SDK with a server-side web app.  My app stores the user's access_token and creates session for the user.  If the user signs out of facebook, they continue to be signed in to my app.  If someone signs into ANOTHER facebook account, the original user continues to be signed in.  However, if I use the Javascript SDK, it would recognize a different user than my app.  The documentation suggests that it supports setting an authResponse, but offers insufficient info on how to do so.